# Update Azure mobile app Asp.Net backend database

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, azure

I have an Azure mobile app with an ASP.NET backend. I want to add a new column to an existing table. I have added the property and redeployed the service but this does not create the column in the table and gives me an error. I also tried to add the column manually with SQL management studio and kept the property in the DataObject class but this still errored. Please could you advise how I can add a new field to the mobile app database.

```
    public class Petrol: EntityData
{

    public int Mileage { get; set; }
    public DateTime PurchaseDate { get; set; }
    public float Quantity { get; set; }
    public Decimal Cost { get; set; }
    public string Station { get; set; }
    public string Claim_Id { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Claim_Id")]
    public virtual Claim Claim { get; set; }


   //This is the new column I would like to add
    public string PhotoUrl { get; set; }

}
```

I have ran the Enable-Migrations command in Package Manager Console, but I am getting an error about the connection string.

Comment: Please share your error of connection string, when running migration, it could be you have not allowed you local PC IP on Azure database to grant firewall access.

Comment: After machine reboot I am no longer getting an error. But when I publish the new column is not being added to the table. I am using Azure slots, do you think this might cause the issue?

Answer (score 0):

The schema of your database is only deployed when your database is empty.

For a database already containing tables you have to implement code first migrations as described here: [Implementing Table Controllers](https://www.google.at/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://adrianhall.github.io/develop-mobile-apps-with-csharp-and-azure/chapter3/server/&ved=0ahUKEwj7rv_Q3tTVAhUJthoKHRHkBPAQFggnMAE&usg=AFQjCNG2CuF5uFqSHaeG5d0zufKDJY8cZA)